# Langchain mapReduce in jupyter Notebook just spinning

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, langchain

I'm new to python and Jupyter notebook so I may be doing something silly here.

I'm following a tutorial on langchain summarizations. I've tried both refine and mapReduce and with both jupyter notebook never completes the summarization step.

My code looks like this:

```py
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), override=True)

with open('files/sample2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=2, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')

llm.get_num_tokens(text)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10000, chunk_overlap=50)
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents([text])

len(chunks)

chain = load_summarize_chain(
    llm,
    chain_type='map_reduce',
    verbose=True
)
output_summary = chain.run(chunks)

print(output_summary)
```

As you can see from the screen shot, load_summarize_chain step is never complete. I've tried multiple times and waited up to an hour. I've also tried using refine instead of map reduce with the same result.

[jupyter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCLUg.png)

I tried shortening the .txt file and starting a new script from scratch.